# Consolidating and raising events based on database inserts/updates?

Tags: .net, wcf, sql-server-2008, events, esb

We have an unfortunate case where a lot of our applications talk directly to the database (native applications mostly, our managed applications go through a DAL). We have 300 + tables and need to raise events based on modifications to certain tables. These events will be raised via an Enterprise Service Bus (nServiceBus) or MSMQ and our applications will hook onto these events.

For example:

- If there is an insert in table 1 and an update in table 2, raise Some events.
- If there is an update in table 1, a delete in table 2 and an update in table 3, raise Some events.

In all we expect there will not be more than 25 events and each events will not touch more than 5 tables at most.

Info:

1. We do a lot of long running tasks and our applications need poll for completion.
2. We have a mix of really old applications which talk directly with the database and changing them to use some sort of a DAL is not an option.
3. We will need to do some primitive event filtering such that some events are only audited and not raised.
4. We are using SQL Server 2008 R, but may not have enterprise licenses at all our installation sites.

We are looking for a CDC like solution which we can hook into. Pointers to possible solutions or input/experiences would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid this, and have avoided it a couple of times.

My backup plan (ie. worked out a sketch but never implemented) was:

- Use triggers to feed messages to a queue
- Use Service Broker to read those messages
- In service broker use a .NET assembly to invoke a WCF service (or perhaps send a message on MSMQ).

Using a queue and Service Broker means the that the triggers don't need to any significant processing and hold up clients.